# How to use curl in python to post some file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to post some file with facebook api to the catalog feed. In the docs I found only curl.

How can I use it in Python? The curl is as follows:

```
curl -F "file=@/Users/username/Projects/facebook-ads/src/vehicles_list.csv;type=text/csv" -F "access_token=...ISGsVL23pvuhmQGJH51uBy0BbljyzXqDOHVOS59qPygPGGm3hZCrfWyTAZCz6tZAX" https://graph.facebook.com/1111111111111111/uploads
```

I tried with `requests` library as folllows:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/1111111111111111/uploads'
payload = open("/Users/boris/Projects/facebook-ads/src/vehicles_list.csv")
headers = {'access_token': '...ISGsVL23pvuhmQGJH51uBy0BbljyzXqDOHVOS59qPygPGGm3hZCrfWyTAZCz6tZAX'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

But it doesnt work.